# Apparent error using ArrayList, but following the syntax given (Stanford CS106A HangmanLexicon)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm nearly finished with a Hangman assignment (taking it independently), and the last task is to create an ArrayList from a .txt file.  I'm following the syntax given but there are two errors that the compiler won't take:

```html
/*
 * File: HangmanLexicon.java
 * -------------------------
 * This file contains a stub implementation of the HangmanLexicon
 * class that you will reimplement for Part III of the assignment.
 */

import acm.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class HangmanLexicon {

 //random number for getWord
 private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
  
 //creates new arraylist
 ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

 
 //opens the text file
 //Reads lines from the file into an ArrayList

 try {
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("HangmanLexicon.txt")); 
  while(rd.readLine() != null) {
  String line = rd.readLine();
  wordList.add(line);
  } 
 } catch (IOException ex) {
  System.out.println("bad/no file");
 }
 
 
// Returns the number of words in the lexicon
 public int getWordCount() {
  int WordCount = wordList.size();
  return WordCount;
 }
 
/** Returns the word at the specified index. */

 public String getWord(int index) {
  int lexnum = rgen.nextInt(0, index);
  String word = wordList.get(lexnum);
  return word;
 };

}
```

The errors are on lines 19 and 37:

19) Arraylist....   Error: "{" expected after ";"

37) public int  getWordCount() { ....  Error: ";" expected

What are the fixes to these?

Comment: Starting at try, you have a bunch of code not inside a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The try-catch block needs to be inside a method or a static block.